# Create Access Token from Existing Token in oauth_access_tokens table in Laravel Passport

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, jwt, laravel-passport

I need to get the currently active (not making a new one) token from the token stored in the oauth_access_tokens table generated by Laravel Passport.

I already tried this code I got from GitHub:
[See Code](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/779#issuecomment-790205533)

I get the token but I always get 401 Unauthenticated from the token that I got from that code, maybe the code miss some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$currentActive Token = Auth::user()->token()
```

in `Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens` you can see this code

```
    /**
     * Get all of the access tokens for the user.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function tokens()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Passport::tokenModel(), 'user_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
```

For get all tokens you can use

```
 Auth::user()->tokens;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need other user tokens too, not just the ones who requesting